# reading binary file (is_open)

Tags: c++, filestream, binaryfiles

I tried to read a binary file which is located at the required location.
Actually, I am trying to read a class from it and put data into a list, I have created a function for that purpose.
Here is the body of that function.

```
list <string> getlist() {
    list <string> menu;

    string name = "test.bin";

    ifstream infile;

    infile.open((char*)(&name), ios::binary);

    if (!infile.is_open())
        cout << "error1"; // brinting error 

    Elements elements = {};

    infile.read((char*)&elements, sizeof(Elements));

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        menu.push_back(elements.item1);
    }

    infile.close();

    return menu;
}
```

Error message executed although the whole process succeed and the function returns data to the list!!!

```
 if (!infile.is_open())
        cout << "error" << endl; // brinting error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this:

```cpp
infile.open((char*)(&name), ios::binary);
```

To this instead:

```cpp
infile.open(name.c_str(), ios::binary);
```

Type-casting the address of a `std::string` object will not give you a valid pointer to the string's character data. That is what the string's `c_str()` (and `data()`) method is meant for.

If you are using a C++11 or later compiler, you don't even need direct access to the character data, as `open()` has an overload that takes a `std::string` as input:

```cpp
infile.open(name, ios::binary);
```

Either way, if `is_open()` returns false then DON'T proceed to call `read()` afterwards. The contents of `elements` will be invalid. You are not checking for that possibility, eg:

```cpp
if (!infile.is_open())
{
    cout << "error opening the file";
    return menu; // <-- ADD THIS!
    // or better, 'throw' an exception instead...
}

if (!infile.read((char*)&elements, sizeof(Elements))) // <-- ADD FAILURE CHECK! 
{
    cout << "error reading from the file";
    return menu; // <-- ADD THIS!
    // or better, 'throw' an exception instead...
} 

...
```

Beyond that, your use of `infile.read()` is questionable, depending on how the `Elements` class is actually declared, which you did not show.  More times than not, it is not safe to read whole classes like this.  You are trying to store `std::string` objects in a `std::list`, so unless the `Elements::item1` member is a fixed-sized `char[]` array then your use of `read()` will likely not work as intended.

Comment: used it and it creates an exception: access violating writing location.

Comment: @AbanoubEmeel you didn't say which line is throwing the AV. But that could very well could be (and likely is) due to your misuse of `read()` after (failing to) open the file. See my updated answer.